# How to callback the Application Layer file from Native Layer file in a Android?

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I have below three files in my Android project (one java file in Application layer,  one cpp file in JNI layer & one cpp file in Native layer).

1. MyActivity.java    (Application Layer)
2. MyJNIInterface.cpp (JNI Interface)
3. MyNativeFile.cpp.  (Native implementation)

I am able to call a api in Native Layer from Application Layer using JNI interface.

Is there a way through which I can have a callback to the Application Layer file (MyActivity.java) from Native Layer file (MyNativeFile.cpp)?

Please share some sample code.

Comment: Take a look here: https://github.com/mkowsiak/jnicookbook/tree/master/recipeNo032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Check [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/hello-jniCallback) sample app provided by Google

Answer (score 0):

Android fully implements standard JNI (except `JNI_CreateJavaVM()`), so callbacks are supported. Note that you must attach your thread to JVM if you want to call Java back from a thread that was not started in Java (e.g. UI thread does not need [AttachCurrentThread()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#attach_current_thread)).